# RandomVariate on multidimensional Bernoulli array

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, hold

Executing...

```
Map[RandomVariate, Map[BernoulliDistribution, RandomReal[1, 5]]]
```

yields the expected result, e.g. `{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}`

However, generalizing this to a three-dimensional array...

```
Map[RandomVariate, Map[BernoulliDistribution, RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5}], {-1}], {-1}]
```

results in:

```
RandomVariate::unsdst: The first argument 0.7464882166556699` is not a valid distribution.
RandomVariate::unsdst: The first argument 0.27407515926140436` is not a valid distribution.
RandomVariate::unsdst: The first argument 0.8186950771196488` is not a valid distribution.
```

I assume that this is somehow related to not holding variables properly as the second output contains expressions such as `BernoulliDistribution[RandomVariate[0.746488]]` in which the order of evaluation is swapped. How can I fix this and why does this **not** happen in the one-dimensional case?

Comment: try `Map[RandomVariate, 
 Map[BernoulliDistribution, RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5}], {-1}], {-2}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. *"How can I fix this?"***

Map `RandomVariate` at `Level` `{-2}`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dists2 = Map[BernoulliDistribution, RandomReal[1, {2, 3}], {-1}];

SeedRandom[1];
Map[RandomVariate, dists2, {-2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}
> ```

You can also use `{Depth @ dists2 - 2}` as the level specification:

```
% == Map[RandomVariate, dists2, {Depth @ dists2 - 2}]
```

> True

**Why?**

```
Level[dists2, {-1}]
```

> ```
>  {0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526, 0.187803, 0.241361, 0.0657388}
> ```

```
Map[foo, dists2, {-1}]
```

> ```
>   {{BernoulliDistribution[foo[0.817389]], 
>   BernoulliDistribution[foo[0.11142]], 
>   BernoulliDistribution[foo[0.789526]]}, {BernoulliDistribution[
>    foo[0.187803]], BernoulliDistribution[foo[0.241361]], 
>   BernoulliDistribution[foo[0.0657388]]}}
> ```

```
Level[dists2, {-2}]
```

> ```
>  {BernoulliDistribution[0.817389], BernoulliDistribution[0.11142], 
>  BernoulliDistribution[0.789526], BernoulliDistribution[0.187803], 
>  BernoulliDistribution[0.241361], BernoulliDistribution[0.0657388]}
> ```

```
Map[foo, dists2, {-2}]
```

> ```
>   {{foo[BernoulliDistribution[0.8173894901710712`]], 
>   foo[BernoulliDistribution[0.11141961113123644`]], 
>   foo[BernoulliDistribution[0.7895259946338515`]]}, {foo[
>    BernoulliDistribution[0.18780314670602638`]], 
>   foo[BernoulliDistribution[0.24136096745765045`]], 
>   foo[BernoulliDistribution[0.06573875950878105`]]}}
> ```

**2. *"why does this not happen in the one-dimensional case?"***

If you map `RandomVariate` at level `{-1}` the same issue happens in 1D case too:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dists1 = Map[BernoulliDistribution, RandomReal[1, 3], {-1}];
SeedRandom[1];
Map[RandomVariate, dists1, {-1}]
```

> [image]

The reason your code works for the 1D case without error is that the default level spec for `Map` is `{1}` (which is the same as `{Depth@list1 -2}).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, faster solution to using `BernoulliDistribution` is the following:

Set up parameters:

```
dims = {5, 5, 5};

p = RandomReal[1, dims];
```

Sample:

```
UnitStep[p - RandomReal[1, dims]]
```

If you need to use a distribution object for some reason, you could do the following:

```
Map[RandomVariate@*BernoulliDistribution, p, {-1}]
```

The reason why your approach did not work was that once you mapped `BernoulliDistribution`, level `{-1}` no longer referred to the elements of the 3D array, but to the values in the `BernoulliDistribution[...]` expressions.

Comment: also a very nice solution!